# When changing one value in cell, automatically fill out other cells

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to make a cell (B7) be able to automatically input value in cells B10:B12 based on the data from B2:D2 (that are put in manually)

**Example:** When putting in the ID `000100`, B10:B12 should have the dates: `01-feb.2019`, `10-feb.-2019`, `12-feb.-2019`

**&**

ID `000200` will then put in `01-mar.2019`, `10-mar.-2019`, `12-mar.-2019` in cell B10:B12

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about how to write a formula?

Answer (score 2):

**paste this in** **B10**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP($B$7,A2:D5,{2,3,4},0)))
```

[image: 1]

**note:** if you will get strange numbers like 43265 etc then you need to **format** B10:B12 **as a date**

**EU syntax: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP($B$7;A2:D5;{2\3\4};0)))`**

Comment: Got an error message using the formula above, but was able to figure the solution out, using the Vlookup part of the function in B10. =VLOOKUP(B7;A1:D4;2) 
Thanks for guiding in the right directions

Comment: @ChristianVinther try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP($B$7;A2:D5;{2\3\4};0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter and should preserve the formatting:

```
=transpose(offset(A1,match(B7,A:A,0)-1,1,1,3))
```